# In how many ways can 7 girls and 3 boys sit on a bench in such a way that every boy sits next to at least one girl. I don't know how to do it

Tags: combinatorics

All in the question. I'm not sure how to do it because I keep running into more problems. Please explain your steps.

Comment: What problems have you run into?  Explaining _your_ steps will be even more helpful to the people trying to help you.

Comment: Well you could try and eliminate cases where every boy does not sit next to any girls. The problem is you can eliminate the case where 3 boys are together but what about two boys on the edge next to each other. But aren't there also cases included in both so how do you prevent double excluding the same case

Comment: Also, this is a direct duplicate of your previous question - if you have problems with or questions about the answers on that one, please use comments there rather than opening a new question.

Comment: I know I apologize but no one was answering :/

Comment: I don't mean to shout, but: you asked your initial question less than an hour ago!  Questions can go days, months, even weeks without being answered; I _strongly_ counsel patience.  And if you can't afford patience about an answer, then you probably shouldn't be going to math.se - instead you should either be going to the chat site or to a TA or someone close by who can help you in real-time.  Asking the same question again is exactly how *NOT* to use this site.

Comment: Alright. I understand. I won't do it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What combinations don't work? Denote by B a boy, by G a girl and by $*$ uknown. Then these are the following combinations that don't work:

$BB********$ (8 possibilities)

$********BB$ (8 possibilities)

and finally the three boys together in the middle (6 possibilities).

Therefore there are $22$ ways to arrange them that don't work. If we note that in total there are $\binom{10}{3}$ arrangements then that means there are $\binom{10}{3}-22$ that do work, since each arrangement has $3!\cdot7!$ ways to put the people then the answer is $(\binom{10}{3}-22)\cdot3!\cdot7!$

Comment: why do you say 5 possibilities for the 3 boys in the middle?

Comment: GBBBGGGGGG, GGBBBGGGGG, GGGBBBGGGG, GGGGBBBGGG, GGGGGBBBGG, GGGGGGBBBG

Comment: Right that was a bit stupid. I didn't think it through. Where does the (10C3) come from. Wouldn't it be 10!. Not necessarily in the way you worked it out but my logic was more along the lines of 10! - combinations that don't work. They do need to be ordered on the bench

Comment: There are 10 spots, we need which of those 3 will be occupied by the boys.

Comment: but how can you take the number of spots occupied by the boys and subtract the number of arrangements that don't work? I don't mean to be rude :) I'm just trying to understand your logic

Comment: If all the boys and girls were identical the would be $\binom{10}{3}$ configurations, but we know there are $22$ that don't work. Therefore the remaining $\binom{10}{3}-22$ do work. And since from each configuration when the girls and boy are identical there are $3!\cdot7!$ when the girls and boys are different we get the result.

Comment: Thanks I think I'm getting it now

Comment: the problem is. I looked and they gave a solution of 2 116 800 = 1 693 440 + 423 360. Idk how they did it without subtracting first of all and they got a different answer to yours. Also. I'm just thinking of this now but just because three boys together can be arranged in 5 ways in the middle, does that account for girls being arranged differently when boys are in the same arrangement

Comment: no, all the beginning calculations assume all girls are equal and all boys are equal, we fix this at the very end by multiplying the solutions by 3!7!

Comment: Well first of all. With BB******* isn't there only one case if we're assuming equal. because GGGGGGG where all girls are equal (8C8)

Comment: no, because we still need to select which of the 8 asteriks is the third boy.

Comment: Let's maybe take a different approach. The total number of arrangements that are different is 10!

Comment: yes, that is the same as $\binom{10}{3}7!3!$

Comment: So lets assume we wanted to isolate the case where there's G********G and there are 5 groups of 3 boys inside there. How would we get the number of possibilities. 7P2 X ?